# sql - Best way to add extra fields to a sql database

Tags: mysql, json

I want to know what is the best way to manage extra fields on a SQL database (MySQL 5.7 in my case) for example I have the products table with the fields

```
create table product(   
 id int auto_increment,
 product_name varcha,r
 description varchar,
 other json,
 primary key(id)
);
```

But in the future if I want to add extra fields like weigth or height I will store the info at other field as json format.
Is a good idea do this? or is better create a new column for each field. and when is a good choice to store data as json format?

Comment: [alter table](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/alter-table.html) and [ETL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extract,_transform,_load) as you go

Comment: *"and when is a good choice to store data as json format?"* That's a **completely** different question from the rest of your question. (And the answer is: When, and only when, you have a *very* good reason you cannot store it normally.)

Comment: You don't need a very good reason. You just need a reason. One reason might be that you have no intention of performing a search against that criteria.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [input unknown number of fields into mysql - best structure for this?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41569614/input-unknown-number-of-fields-into-mysql-best-structure-for-this)

Answer (score 1):

Well, it all depends on your needs.

If the structure of these "extra" fields will change from row to row, use something lika a `json` encoded text could be a good idea as long as you never need to do an SQL operation over them (as, for example, a `WHERE` condition).

Anyway (and as long as your extra fields structure is variable from row to row), I would recommend to use another table where you can store all of the extra atributes, for example:

```
 CREATE TABLE extra_attributes(
     id integer not null primary key,
     product_id integer not null,
     attribute_name varchar(64) not null,
     attribute_value varchar(128)
 );
```

And then create a foreign key to `products` table.

If all of your products have the same extra fields, the simplest solution will be to add the needed columns to tha product table.