# Table field max length for geolocation

Tags: mysql, maxlength

What is the max length of result of http://ip-api.com/docs/api:serialized_php ?

```
[region] => XX
[timezone] => Europe/Paris
[org] => Free SAS
[query] => 78.221.XXX.XXX
[regionName] => Upper Garonne
[zip] => 31320
[lat] => XX.111111111111
[lon] => YY.1111111111111
[as] => ZZ11111 PROXAD
[status] => success
[country] => NNNNNN
[countryCode] => UU
[city] => AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
[isp] => DDDD DD
```

To avoid requesting this api multiple times for the same IP address, I would like to store the result in a MySQL database. But I don't know how long can be the results.

I mean, it's specific to the ip-api.com. If I specify a column of varchar 100 for regionName. Can a regionName have more than 100 characters?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [input unknown number of fields into mysql - best structure for this?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41569614/input-unknown-number-of-fields-into-mysql-best-structure-for-this)

Comment: You can save in text type column.

Comment: @jyotimishra http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41198808/storing-large-json-binary-or-text/41199218?s=7|0.0000#41199218

Comment: I mean, it's specific to the ip-api.com. If I specify a column of varchar 100 for regionName. Can a regionName have more than 100 characters?